# Set JMeter to start thread groups after 10 seconds

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a JMeter Test Plan setup with 15 different thread groups.

Each thread group contains different HTTP requests.

Every thread group is setup to have only 1 user (number of threads) and not to loop,  So that all requests only run once.

When I start the test to run I want JMeter to start the 1st thread group and then I want the 2nd thread group to start after 10 seconds. The 3rd to start after 20 seconds (from when the 1st one started) and so on.

How can I set this up?  Ramp up period isn't the answer.

Here are my thread groups: 
[image]

I want the thread group Batch cs1 to start running the requests it has (each http request it has takes awhile to run, over minutes).  Then I want to wait 10 seconds and have thread group Batch cs2 to run.  Then I want to wait another 10 seconds and have thread group Batch cs3 to run, and so on until all thread groups have been started and running.
Do I just have the test plan setup wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use Flow Control Action at the starting of each thread group except for the first group(no need to check Run Thread Groups Consecutively option). In 2nd thread group's control action, use 10000 ms, 3rd thread group control action, use 20000ms (or whatever time interval you may want) and so on.
I have tried this with 6 thread groups.
[image: sample test plan]

So when I replayed the test plan, 'HTTP Request1' started immediately and 'HTTP Request2' started at 10th second and 'HTTP Request3' started at 20th second and so on..
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) at the start of your thread groups with pause time of 10000 milliseconds

In Test Plan check `Run Thread Groups consecutively` so it will execute one thread group at a time.

Comment: I don't want the thread groups to run consecutively, I want them to run concurrent.  What I want is the 1st run to start, wait 10 seconds and have the next one run, and so on.  I have 15 thread groups, 1 user and no loop.  Each thread group has 3 http requests that each take over a minute to run.  I didn't add Flow Control Action to the 1st thread group, I added it to the other 14 thread groups in increments of 10 seconds.  But when I ran the test it ran http requests from all over the place, thread group 1 wasn't even the first to run

Comment: @coreysnow it sound you want **thread groups** to be executed **consecutively** and because you have 1 user you don't need concurrent users

Comment: no @user7294900 I want them concurrent, I don't want them consecutively.  I updated the question and pasted a screenshot, hopefully that clarifies what I'm looking for a little more.

Comment: @corey..from the update..it seems consecutive Thread group execution..but that doesn't mean consecutive threads execution. Click on test plan and check (first option) "Run thread groups consecutively". So, it will start with cs1 , you need Flow control action in cs1 also, in the end to wait for some time. Then, it will start cs2 and again after http requests it will wait due to Flow control action for wait...and so on.

Comment: Thread groups controls number of threads while Test plan control thread group execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the startup delay (seconds) as 0 for first thread group, 10 for second thread group, 20 for third thread group, etc.

[image]